# Possibility of cancelling Summer Internship at a start-up due to COVID-19

Tags: interviewing, human-resources, internship, canada

I recently got an internship offer at a start-up for Summer.

Here is the offer I received on *March 14*.

> The team really appreciated meeting with you, and we would like to
>   extend you an offer for an internship position starting in May 2020
>   for a four months duration. We would be able to offer you a * CAD
>   annual pay (to be prorated to the duration of your internship).  Shall
>   you accept this internship, I’ll make an official offer when we will
>   agree on the exact starting and ending dates.

I replied to them that I accept the offer on the same date and send them I could start to work on May 1 or May to August 31.

However, until now, I have not heard back from them. On another note, it seems the company is very slow in terms of hiring. I submitted my application back in nearly November 2019 and got an interview in February 2020.

Also, I sent another follow-up email to ask the exact start date and end date on *March 20*. Still, they have not replied yet.

What do you think? Should I worry about it? Nerve-racking is so horrible.

Thanks for any input and I hope all of us get the jobs and stay healthy!

Comment: You realize 21-22 was a *weekend* right? If they haven't responded by mid/early April, then you can start to worry.

Comment: Your question reads like *you* want to cancel the internship. You should probably edit that. Also, you've given no reasons to suspect that covid plays any part in this slowness at all.

Comment: The concern is that they didn't reply to me for a week after I accept the offer. Yeah, I just read a lot of news that COVID-19 will cause the next recession and then most companies will freeze hiring.  so I am pretty worried. :(

Comment: Hiring processes are usually pretty nerve-racking, but it's important to 1) Stay objective and 2) Don't worry about things out of your power. You're worrying way too soon! Good luck with your internship

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Companies typically move at the speed of dirt and you'll rarely see anything done during the weekend.

Take a step back and relax. They already offered you the position and have said nothing about the virus, so don't jump to conclusions.

Give it a couple weeks. That's a normal time-frame when things have already been generally decided, but no one is in a rush (on their side) to decide the details.

Answer (score 0):

**I would be making contingency plans, i.e. back to the job hunt**

I just graduated last year, so I am still reasonably well tied into the student community. Internships are rapidly being canceled left and right. Obviously not everyone is losing their internship, but the count is rising. A lot of internships are disappearing, even with some of the larger companies.

Go back out there and keep hunting as not hearing means they might be considering cancellation. In a normal year, you might be overreacting, but not this year.

Comment: Yes, that's what I am worried about. Sigh, this is a company I really want to work for. Thanks for your suggestions!

Comment: @Andy You may still get the internship. But under the circumstances, it is prudent to have other options.

Comment: I think this should really be framed differently. It sounds to me like "well, time to panic and restart my internship hunt" when it should really just be "continue the hunt you were on and don't close any doors *yet*".